# Update Imageview from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i already have a listview with ImageView and then start downloading a list of images for it with the help of AsyncTask (universal downloader for any type of file in my app).
After each downloaded image i need to insert it to ImageView. So I think i need some kind of callback from my AsyncTask to main thread, but how to do it i dont know?

Here is my AsyncTask code

DownloadFileFromURL down = (DownloadFileFromURL) new DownloadFileFromURL(Destination).execute("http://example.com");

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String Destination;

public DownloadFileFromURL(String UrlDestination){
    this.Destination=UrlDestination;
}

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
        // progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);
        // Output stream

        Log.d("City.xml:",this.Destination);

        File targetFile = new File(this.Destination);
        File parent = targetFile.getParentFile();
        if(!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()){
            Log.e("Error: ", ": " + parent);
        }


        //OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/"+this.Destination);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ",  e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Method `onPostExecute(result)` is called from `UI Thread` so you can modify your `ListView` from it.

UPDATE:

You can create interface:

```
interface IOnFileDownloadedListener{

    public void onFileDownloaded(String filePath); // or type other than string
}
```

then in your class `DownloadFileFromURL` you can pass class implementing `IOnFileDownloadedListener` somehow (for example in constructor).

Then after downloading file you can check if listener is null (if you decide to allow not passing any listener) and if it is not null, you can call `onFileDownloaded`

```
public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private String Destination;
private IOnFileDownloadedListener Listener = null;

public DownloadFileFromURL(String UrlDestination){
    this.Destination=UrlDestination;
}

public DownloadFileFromURL(String UrlDestination, IOnFileDownloadedListener FDListener){
    this(UrlDestination);
    Listener = FDListener;
}

...

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    if(this.Listener != null) this.Listener.onFileDownloaded(this.Destination);
}
```

Comment: i use this DownloadFileFromURL class to download different files, not only images, so i would like to save it more universal, a not modify it or set it to specific ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can Load easly images from server using library **Picasso**:

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Here's an example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://yoururlserver.com/yourimage.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [simple library to display images in Android ListView](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the library Android Universal Image Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

You can easilly load with:

```
String imageUri = "http://www.yoursite.com/image.png"; // Image url
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView); // imageView - your imageView
```